# jquery toggle question

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to create a master toggle function that will collapse/expand all the mini toggles. my mini toggle function is:

```
$('.tog').toggle(
   function(){ 
      $('#togStat').val(1);
      var myID = $(this).attr("id").split('-')[1];
      $('#collapseObj-'+myID).hide();
      $('#collapseImg-'+myID).attr({src:'images/collapse_tcat_collapsed.gif'});
   },
   function(){ 
      $('#togStat').val(0);
      var myID = $(this).attr("id").split('-')[1];
      $('#collapseObj-'+myID).show();
      $('#collapseImg-'+myID).attr({src:'images/collapse_tcat.gif'});
});
```

and the master one is:

```
    <cfoutput>
      $('.togAll').toggle(
   function(){
      <cfloop from="1" to="10" index="i">
      $('##collapseObj-#i#').hide();
      $('##collapseImg-#i#').attr({src:'images/collapse_tcat_collapsed.gif'});
      </cfloop>
      $('##collapseImg-All').attr({src:'images/expand_icon.png'}); 
      $('##collapseImg-All').attr({title:'expand all'}); 
      $('##collapseImg-All').attr({alt:'expand all'}); 
   },
   function(){ 
      <cfloop from="1" to="#getMaxCatID.catID#" index="i">
      $('##collapseObj-#i#').show();
      $('##collapseImg-#i#').attr({src:'images/collapse_tcat.gif'});
      </cfloop>
      $('##collapseImg-All').attr({src:'images/collapse_icon.png'}); 
      $('##collapseImg-All').attr({title:'collapse all'});
      $('##collapseImg-All').attr({alt:'collapse all'});
      });
      </cfoutput>
```

i am using coldfusion. the master function loops through 1 to X and creates something similar to:

```
 $('#collapseObj-1').hide();
 $('#collapseObj-2').hide();
 $('#collapseObj-1').hide();
```

my problem is when i click on the master toggle, i have to double click on the mini toggles in order to open the collapsed divs. is there a way to change toggle(even,odd) to toggle(odd,even) ? 
thanks

Comment: off-topic: you can chain your jQuery commands without having to re-select the nodes: `$('some selector').show().attr(...);` additionally, most of the objects you're passing to `attr` can be condensed into one call.

Comment: i tried doing : attr({src:'images/collapse_icon.png'},{title:'collapse all'},...);  but it didn't like it. maybe i should do   $('##collapseImg-All').attr({src:'images/collapse_icon.png'}).attr({title:'collapse all'}).attr({alt:'collapse all'});

Comment: No, he's saying to do `$('#element_id').attr({key1:val1, key2:val2, key3:val3});` You should read up on [jQuery basics](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).

Comment: that works. so, i created a tog_alt class which has the hide/show in reverse order. i tried $('##collapseImg-#i#').removeClass('tog').addClass('tog_alt'); but this won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work attached to an onclick action:

```
   if (!$('#collapseObj-1').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#collapseObj-1').hide();
        $('#collapseImg-1').attr({src:'images/collapse_tcat.gif'});
     } else {
        $('#collapseObj-1').show();     
        $('#collapseImg-1').attr({src:'images/collapse_tcat_collapsed.gif'});
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, jQuery.toggle actually toggles visibility. You seem to consider it like a function that has a onShow and onHide parameter, which is wrong. See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. The way you wrote it, you have 2 functions as parameters, but toggle takes either

- boolean showOrHide
- int duration, function callback
- int duration, string easing, function callback

Clearly your use of `.toggle()` is wrong. If you want to change the visibility when a certain event happens, you could write it with a function that shows/hides one mini toggle based on its current visibility. I cannot see what `#togStat` does, but I kept it in.

```
var togStat = $('#togStat');

function miniToggle(id) {
    var elem = $('#collapseObj-' + id);
    if (elem.is(':visible')) {
        togStat.val(1);
        elem.hide();
        $('#collapseImg-' + id).attr({src: 'images/collapse_tcat_collapsed.gif'});
    } else {
        togStat.val(0);
        elem.show();
        $('#collapseImg-' + id).attr({src: 'images/collapse_tcat.gif'});
    }
}
```

You could call this for an element number (like in your example) like this:

```
miniToggle(1);
```

I hope this helps you. If not, you might want to post an example page so we can check out the actual code.

Comment: if (elem.is(':visible'))  is always true. it doesn't see the hide() event.

Comment: If (elem.is(':visible')) is true, elem is hidden and on the next call it won't be true. Also I'd appreciate any info on why this got marked down. Did I misunderstand the question?